# How to show beta equivalence of property of Y combinator

Tags: lambda-calculus

How to show that $\underline{Y}f =_{\beta} f(\underline{Y}f)$ where $\underline{Y}$ is the usual Y combinator?

Thanks.

Comment: There are many fixed point combinators. Please, give the explicit definition of the $\lambda$-term $Y$, otherwise your question is meaningless. Moreover, what's the difference between $ Y$ and $\underline{Y}$?

Comment: I wouldn't say this question is meaningless. Curry's $Y$ combinator is the first and pretty much the only fixed point combinator covered in undergraduate courses, and I think it's not very ambiguous to call it "the usual $Y$ combinator". Apart from this, I do agree that the $\underline{Y}$ is a bit confusing, and I wonder what they meant by that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by "the usual $Y$ combinator" you mean Curry's fixed point combinator:

$$ Y = \lambda f . (\lambda x . f (x x)) (\lambda x. f(x x)) $$

The property $Y F \equiv_\beta F(Y F)$ can be proven as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}
YF &\equiv_\beta^\star (\lambda x . F (x x)) (\lambda x. F(x x)) & (1)\\
&\equiv_\beta^\star F ((\lambda x . F (x x)) (\lambda x. F(x x)))& (2)\\
&\equiv F(YF)& (3)
\end{aligned}$$

*Where $\equiv_\beta^\star$ is the transitive and reflexive closure of the beta-reduction*.

1. The $Y$ combinator is applied to $F$
2. The recursion happens; the first $(\lambda x. F(x x))$ is applied to the second, obtaining exactly the expression from (1), but "wrapped" inside an $F$.
3. Since what we had before was equivalent to $YF$, the result is $F(YF)$.